# What does this typedef mean and what is it good for?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I've stumbled upon this typedef:

```
typedef char (&small)[1];
typedef char (&large)[2];
```

I know `&` either as the reference qualifier or the address-of-operator. Since we are dealing with types here, I'd guess it's a reference, but do the parenthesis have a special purpose?

In the context I got it from it is used to perform a compile time check for convertibility of types, how can this typedef help in this matter?

Comment: small is a reference to a char array of size 1, large is a reference to a char array of size 2.

Comment: And the parantheses are because `[]` binds before `&` (in a declarator): w/o the parantheses, `char &small[1]` would be an *array of one reference to a `char`*, which is illegal (arrays of references are not allowed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `typedef`s define references to arrays of `char`: `small` is an array of one `char` and `large` as an array of two `char`. The purpose of `typedef`s of this kind is to have them returned from a property checker based on overloading: if the property exists one is returned otherwise the other is returned. The result is then used `sizeof()` to determine the property, e.g.:

```
template <typename B, typename S>
struct is_base_of_helper {
    static small test(B*);
    static large test(void*, ...);
};
template <typename B, typename S>
struct is_base_of {
    enum value { 1 == sizeof(is_base_of_helper<B, S>::test(static_cast<S*>(0)) };
};
```

The test may semantically not be quite accurate but the idea is: call an overloaded function in a `sizeof()` operation and test the size of the result. Depending on which overload is chosen the presence of a type property can be determined. Using references to arrays has the nice property that their size can be predicated (1 and 2 for `small` and `large`, respectively). Using, e.g., the size of built-in types doesn't work reliably because they can all have the same size.

... and, yes, the parenthesis matter: without the parenthesis it would be an illegal attempt to create an array of references rather than a reference to an array. Only the latter gives the size guarantees this is after.

Comment: So `char` is selected arbitrarily here? If I understood you correctly, the array is chosen because there is no guarantee that sizeof(T1) != sizeof(T2) otherwise. But `int (&small)[1]` would have worked just as well?

Comment: @mel- Why wouldn't it? Also, as to why the parens are needed: `&` has lower precedence than `[]` in declarations, so `char &small[1]` is parsed as `char &(arr[1])`, and AFAIK it's illegal, you can't declare an array of references.

Comment: It would have worked to use `int (&small)[1]`. However, an array with one `char` has the property that its size is 1: `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1 and the size of a type is the number of `char`s by which two adjacent objects in an array are separated. That is, if `int` would have been used, the test would have needed to use `sizeof(int)` rather than 1.

Answer (score 1):

These statements `typedef` reference to array of size one, and size two respectively. This is an example:

```
/*
 foo accepts arrays of size 10 only!
*/
void foo(int (&array)[10])
{ ... }
```

another example:

```
/*
 foo accepts arrays of size len!
 The size is len, so you can know the size of the array
 unlike when using a pointer to int.
 (unless you pass the size in the next parameter, of course!)
*/
template <std::size_t len>
void foo(int (&array)[len])
{ ... }
```